# apply to an xts object in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I have an `xts` object. I would like to take an average for each row and merge it back to my object.  Ex:

```
require(xts)
obj = xts(matrix(1:100, ncol=2), order.by=seq.Date(from=as.Date("2012-01-01"), by=1, length=50))
another_obj = apply(obj, 1, mean)
```

This is now just a vector with dates as names.

```
class(another_obj)
   [1]  "numeric"
```

I could again convert this to `xts` and use the names as the `order.by` and then merge everything back to obj but this is quite tedious.

```
another_obj = as.xts(another_obj, order.by=as.Date(names(another_obj)))
obj = merge(obj, another_obj)
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will add a column with the mean of each row

```
obj <- cbind(obj, rowMeans(obj))
```

**EDIT** clarify why the `cbind` is working here:

Here I am using `cbind.xts` wich is a call `merge.xts`. So the above is equivalent to :

```
obj <- merge(obj, rowMeans(obj))
```

Comment: thanks! always get a bit worried with just `cbinding` time-series together but i guess in this case it's guaranteed they will line up.

Comment: could you please explain how this works? `rowMeans` will return a vector not an `xts` so how will merging be called here?

Comment: I think it will assign the same dates to the rowMeans(obj), merge the 2 , and return an xts object because the default `retcalss` of `merge` is xts.

Comment: right so this is basically the classic `cbind`. it works great here just want to make sure

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
   obj <- as.xts(transform(obj, another_obj=rowMeans(obj)))
```

Comment: This changes the class of obj to `zoo`

Comment: @geektrader thanks for the comment, I edited so that the class remains `xts`